Sandbox: bash(2538) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/.../ios/App/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-App/Pods-App-frameworks.sh
I'm working on an Ionic iOS project and since I upgraded to macOS Sonoma 14.4.1 I get this error when I try to build my project in xcode 15.3.
I tried

cleaning the build folder
executing pod deintegrate, pod clean and pod install
upgrading cocoa pods with gem install cocoapods

If I set User Script Sandboxing to No, the application builds, but I still get the error when I'm building the exact same commit/version on Ionic Appflow, which I have to do to publish the Application in the App Store.

I managed to get it to build by changing User Script Sandboxing to No on both, the target and the app.
